# Retag Request [vc++] -> [visual-c++]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

It seems that:

- [[vc++]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vc++) (466)

would be more clearly expressed as

- [[visual-c++]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-c++) (1,697)

Comment: If I make all those changes by hand, do I get the bounty?

Comment: I love that. For the benefit of the visual-c++ community you sacrifice your hard-earned reputation for a bounty... and make a huge profit! :-)

Comment: Haha. Except the question already had 9 upvotes before the bounty...

Comment: I can't believe I've got the only question on Meta with a bounty -- and it's for something simple like this -- and it's had no chance of happening yet :P

Comment: @Billy: Then consider it a prediction! ;-)

+13 and counting...

Comment: @Billy: Trinkets of reputation? The retag Gods crave not such things. Maybe try offering up some unicorns.

Comment: @Mike Howard: Unfortunately the Unicorns started to avoid me when they found out I would be using them as currency. :(

Comment: Phase 1: Ask retag question. Phase 2: ????? Phase 3: Profit!

Comment: And look! 5 bountied questions on Meta now. I think some people thought they could take that a bit too far :)

Comment: Billy, wouldn't it be better to leave the question open so some mod actually will take care of it?

Comment: @gf: What do you mean? I didn't vote to close it, and the bounty auto-accepted James McNellis' answer.

Comment: @Billy: Ah, didn't know that :) And then i admit that i don't know wether the mods filter by "has accepted answer" or by `[status-completed]`.

Comment: isn't this [status-completed] now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some more...

```
[msvc] (172)
[visual-studio] [c++] (639)
[visual-c++-2005] (54)
[visual-c++-2008] (11)
[visual-c++-2010] (3)
[visual] [c++] (2)
```

(all of those counts are also searching `-[visual-c++]`).

Comment: What do you suggest the tags like [visual-c++-2005] be retagged to?

Comment: @Jon:  My thought is that it's probably best for those to be tagged both with the more generic `[visual-c++]` and with the more specific version-number tag.  I probably could have just gone and retagged them, but only had a moment while I was searching for them.

Comment: I need to point out an issue with the tag counts. There is an annoying [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46060/tag-search-not-operator-is-broken) with the search box with regards to NOTing tags out of a search. I'm going to update your post with the real counts.

Comment: @Jon:  Thanks.  Wow if that isn't an obnoxious and unexpected bug :-).  I thought those counts were way too small.