# How can I search for questions that do NOT include a given tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

I was led to believe that `-[tag]` would do this, but it doesn't appear to.

Comment: There seems to be no way at the moment. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=

Comment: Even the mighty Google do not support only negative query. But, they do support `site:` + negative: http://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions+-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tag search functionality is... limited... and completely broken in many complex cases when using the `NOT` operator.

Your best bet is to keep the search as simple as possible. Most of what you need to know is covered in my bug report [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46060/tag-search-not-operator-is-broken).

To summarize, here are some common cases you might try when doing an advanced search:

- `[tag1] -[tag2]` -- works! (it's all downhill from here, so hopefully this is sufficient)
- `-[tag1]` -- disallowed because the result set would be too big
- `-[tag2] [tag1]` -- disallowed
- `[tag1] -[tag2-~]` -- broken -- expands as `[tag1] and -[tag2-a] or [tag2-b] or [tag2-c]` instead of `[tag1] and -([tag2-a] or [tag2-b] or [tag2-c])`
- `[tag2-~] -[tag1]` -- broken -- expands as `[tag2-a] or [tag2-b] or [tag2-c] or -[tag1]` instead of `([tag2-a] or [tag2-b] or [tag2-c]) and -[tag1]`
- `[tag1] -[tag2] other search terms` -- appears to be broken -- looks like the `NOT` operator is simply ignored

I could swear I had a comment discussion with Jeff about the ~ operator leaking out those `OR`s, but it was so long ago that I doubt I can find it at this point. He saw what was wrong, but I guess it never got fixed.

Anyhow, with the wildcards, even the erroneous expansions don't seem to produce correct search results... so at this point, don't even bother trying that. Wildcard searches *on their own* or in combination with other `AND`ed tags work fine. It's only when the `NOT` operator is introduced that everything blows up... but that's what you asked for in this question, so there it is.

Comment: I did look at it -- the fix was kind of difficult. Apologies.

Comment: @Jeff: Okay, as long as you looked at it. Obviously it's not a high-priority bug, but it would be nice to get it fixed. I think the most important one out of the ones I've listed above would be the tags + free text searching with a `NOT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but a query cannot have merely a not clause.

NOT SOMETHING

is disallowed, but

SOMETHING AND NOT OTHER

is allowed

Comment: So is there something wrong with http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]%20-[html]%20open+link+new+window , because that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Anyone know what's wrong with the example in my previous comment?

Comment: @Bobby - Looks like you can only do tags without a search term if you do a `not` search. ----------- The `not` search would seem like something that should be in [ **the search FAQ** ](http://stackoverflow.com/search).

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this with tags alone using `questions/tagged`. You can use the form `-tag`, in conjunction with another tag: `questions/tagged/this+-that`

The `not` functionality will not work in a search, so there's no way to add a search term.

So this **will work**:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-html

The above selects all `[javascript]` that are not `[html]`.

If you try and add a search term it will only **look** like you're selecting questions that are not in a tag.

For example to try and search "open link new window" in `[javascript]` but not [`html]`, you can try the following.

This **will not work**.

> [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+[-html]+open+link+new+window](http://bit.ly/co3EHZ)

This will take you to **[a page](http://bit.ly/co3EHZ)** that **says** `not HTML`, but that's not true:

[image]
(*click to enlarge*)

---

You can try Google with something like:

> [open link new window +javascript -html site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=open+link+new+window+%2Bjavascript+-html+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: It works if you just search by tags (IE without the "open link in new window").

Comment: @Simon - Thanks. Didn't know that. Nice feature. - Though it's not really a search, since it just redirects to `questions/tagged`.