# Searching for not a tag broken

Tags: bug, search, tag-search

I'm a weird person, looking on codegolf.stackexchange.com for the rare questions not labelled [code-golf].

I type '-[code-golf]' into the search box and get `results found containing "-[code-golf]" tagged with not code-golf`. However, when I move to page 2 of the search results, I start getting questions tagged with code-golf, and the search has changed to just `results found containing "-[code-golf]"`

[Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bcode-golf%5D) is the search.

Comment: I think this might be [status-bydesign], because of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/46060/323179). A workaround is adding something meaningless to the search so that it's more than a negated tag, like this: `* -[code-golf]`.